# EF Core Migrations: Drop Unique Constraint when it exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

**Context**

I have a table in SQL Server which has a unique index on four columns of a table.

When using `migrationBuilder.AlterColumn` from EF Core migrations, it first tries to script a `DROP INDEX` script which cannot be performed on a `UNIQUE INDEX`. To combat this, I can use `migrationBuilder.DropUniqueConstraint` which will work, as long as that constraint exists.

**The issue**

Some developers don't have the database locally, and will run all migration scripts from scratch. This means that the `UNIQUE INDEX` will be created, but there is no data so there will be no `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`. In this situation, a SQL exception is thrown because the constraint does not exist.

I tried making use of `migrationBuilder.Sql` and doing a `IF EXISTS` statement, where it checks if the constraint exists, then drop it. However, it does not seem to either execute this correctly, or at all.

**Question?**

Is there something wrong with my statement, or is there an easier way to solve this?

**Statement**

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='CONSTRAINT_NAME')
            BEGIN
                ALTER COLUMN COLUMN_NAME DROP CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME
            END");
```

Comment: So why is there sometimes a unique constraint and sometimes a unique index?  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: In the migration InitialCreate script, we add a unique index. The constraint only appears to be present when we have data in the table.

Comment: A constraint won't magically appear.  A unique constraint creates an index, but not vice-versa.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you have any idea how a unique constraint could be present currently in our database, without anything being manually added in?

Comment: Potentially you have someone adding constraints and indexes from another tool, such as SSMS. You shouldn't do that in code-first application databases because at some point it can/will break migrations.

Comment: From what we can gather, it was a mistake made during the time when the project was Database First. We then moved to Code First, and the migrations were no longer accurate compared to the database itself. 
Solution was to drop the constraint manually on existing databases, keep the index, and restore the migration scripts to be just simple calls to `migrationBuilder.AlterColumn`.

Still not sure why the code in my `.Sql` script didn't work though, but I guess not important now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, we determined what the issue was.

We initially took an EF Core database first approach, where SSMS was used to script a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, which in turn created the `UNIQUE INDEX`.

Later we used the scaffolding with migrations to make the `InitialCreate` migration, to move to code first. During this step, it generated `modelBuilder` code to create a `UNIQUE INDEX`, but not the constraint. This meant that our migration scripts were no longer in sync with the state of our existing databases which were initially database first.

The solution was to stop trying to drop the constraint (which we didn't even need) in the migration scripts, and to remove it from our existing databases.